# htaccess rule, rewriting without redirecting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

What I'm attempting to do is changing the URL showed in the navigation without redirecting. I need to do this because I believe it helps to achieve a better ranking on search engines.

Heres an example of the URL:

```
example.com/en/~17558/product-description-037060
```

In any case, I need it to look like this:

```
example.com/en/product-description-037060-17558
```

Would somebody be able to please guide me to accomplish the result?

Comment: How far did you go trying this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*~.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*)$ ~$2/
```